# Set copy constructor as default does not work when inherited from QObject

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to set copy constructor as default, but compiler alert with "... attempting to reference a deleted function". What's wrong with my code?

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    const QString s1;
    ...
    const QString sn;
    const QDateTime t1;
    ...
    const QDateTime tn;


    A() = delete;
    A(const QString &s1, ...);
    A(const A&) = default;
    ~A() = default;

    float fun1();
    ...
    float funn();

private:
    QString m_s1;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

[QObject Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator) description page says following:

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
>   Object Model page. That means you are not supposed to copy QT objects,
>   since QObject is non-copyable by design.

Which means `QObject` can't be copied and all its descendants can't be copied also.

**But**

You may convert your class to `QVariant` which uses a copy ctor

```
void *ptr = QMetaType::construct(x->type, copy);
```